# What transformation to apply before linear regression?

Tags: least-squares, data-transformation, nonlinear-regression

I'm trying to remove the autocorrelation from a time series with linear regression based on past values.  But as this plot shows (`y` is 1-step head values averaged for each `x` which is 100 groups of ordered previous values), the relationship is highly non-linear: [image]

Since there's a very distinctive shape, is there a standard approach to transforming the data before using ordinary least squares?

Comment: You might be better off modeling with some nonlinearity.

Comment: That's what I was planning to do by applying a nonlinear transform to the data before using OLS.  Or do you mean I should be using a different kind of regression?

Comment: I mean some kind of nonlinearity in the regression itself, perhaps using splines. But it will matter what the goal of your modeling is...so what is the goal of your modeling.

Comment: The goal is to generate predictions that will be added to the original time series to produce a new series with no autocorrelation.  I'd prefer a parametric method with no more than 2-4 parameters.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the autocorrelation? That is an important facet of time series data.

Comment: Prediction is hopeless: absent additional information or assumptions, any reasonable prediction method will, when applied to these data, produce predictions that go through the roof and have enormous error estimates.  Why don't you explain what these data mean and what you really need to accomplish, rather than insisting on applying time series techniques which are bound to fail?